# Pdf load the whole file to show it to the viewer

Tags: wordpress, performance, pdf, server, vps

Why would a pdf viewer load the whole file before it open it ?
and when I moved the website to another server it loaded faster, is this related to the server settings? any idea?

Main server with the problem:
[https://www.mnhji.com/حل-كتاب-الانجليزي-ثالث-متوسط-ف2-1442/](https://www.mnhji.com/%D8%AD%D9%84-%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B2%D9%8A-%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%B7-%D9%812-1442/)

second server that works:
[https://www.mnhji.com/حل-كتاب-الانجليزي-ثالث-متوسط-ف2-1442/](https://www.mnhji.com/%D8%AD%D9%84-%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B2%D9%8A-%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%B7-%D9%812-1442/)

I’m using wordpress, and I’ve changed the themes and plugins.

Comment: Basically the PDF file has a table of contents that is at the end of the file. However there are "web optimized PDFs" that don't need the end of the file. Meaning: It depends on the PDF file. Acobat Reader will show the type in the document properties.

Comment: You’re right, I have also a lot of web optimized files uploaded and still facing the same issue. The thing that it works very well in the second server. Just the first server the pdf files take so much time to load the whole file first.

Comment: The other thing is that the server has to support reading random parts of a file; in case the file is created dynamically, that may not work. See also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.12.